# ui.router named views not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router

I am trying to define nested state with the named views.
But it is not working, please see the below code and plunk.
What could be the problem with this.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/profiles/calendar');
        $stateProvider
            .state('profiles', {
              url : '/profiles',
              abstract : true,
            })
            .state('profiles.calendar', {
                url: '/profiles/calendar',
                views: {
                    "": {
                        template: '<div>' +
                            '  <h1>Main</h1>' +
                            '  <div ui-view="leftSidePaneModule"></div>' +
                            '</div>',
                    },
                    'leftSidePaneModule@profiles.calendar': {
                        template: '<div>' + 
                                  '  <div ui-view="leftWidgetOne"></div>' + 
                                  '  <div ui-view="leftWidgetTwo"></div>' +
                                  '</div>',
                    },
                    'leftWidgetOne@profiles.calendar': {
                        template: '<h2>One</2>',
                    },
                    'leftWidgetTwo@profiles.calendar': {
                        template: '<h2>Two</2>',
                    },
                }
            });
    })
```

Here is the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/nhzHMixgP4hOLmLoPbYv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Check the updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MSfFl9RxO7zF407NsIsS?p=preview).

instead of this:

```
.state('profiles.calendar', {
    url: '/profiles/calendar',
```

we have to use this:

```
.state('profiles.calendar', {
    url: '/calendar',
```

because we call:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/profiles/calendar');
```

and the url is concatenated from parent and child states... so without that change it would be:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/profiles/profiles/calendar');
```

There is also another setting:

- [Absolute Routes (`^`)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-) *(small cite and code snippet from doc:)*

> If you want to have absolute url matching, then you need to prefix your url string with a special symbol `'^'`.

code snippet:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {
     url: '/contacts',
     ...
  })
  .state('contacts.list', {
     url: '^/list',
     ...
  });
```

So the third solution would be:

```
.state('profiles.calendar', {
    url: '^/profiles/calendar', // see the leading sign
```

*But I guess the url shortening as I showed in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MSfFl9RxO7zF407NsIsS?p=preview) is the best way to go...*